# Why does second function iteration only add [MemNo], no other data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

So with the way I've coded, users have their option of 3 data sources when querying through my Winforms Application: SOURCE1, SOURCE2, BOTH. For either SOURCE1 or SOURCE2 my code functions just fine, querying the 400 system for data and looping through the datareader to place the data in a ListView control.

When a user select BOTH as the datasource, my query string becomes "SELECT ... FROM X; SELECT ... FROM Y".

400 System Queries I guess are different than a SQL Server system, not letting you try to do multiple SELECTS in one hit by using a semicolon (;) to separate queries. So to combat this I am calling my GetISeriesData() function twice when my query string contains a semicolon (;). My code processes with the first query, then repeats and uses the second query.

What I'm getting is some really strange behavior with no error:

[image: Result]

The SOURCE1 query functions perfectly, retrieving all available data and filling the ListView control as expected. The second iteration of the code that uses SOURCE2 however, is only filling the [MemNo] field of the ListView.

I have verified the other data is successfully being returned, and by stepping through, code-wise, the values should be getting inserted into the control. Can anyone spot something I may be overlooking? For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is happening.

**CODE**:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvData.Clear();
            string qryCmd = "";

            createColumns();

            switch (cmbLetterType.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("oldAddr");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("newAddr");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    qryCmd = chkSystem("nameChg");
                    break;
            }

            // If the option for BOTH is selected, qryCmd is a long string containing the individual queries for SOURCE1 and SOURCE2.
            // Here I check if a semicolon (;) exists, denoting that there are 2 cmd queries in the string.
            // If so, I split the query calling GetiSeriesData() with the first query string, then assigning qryCmd the second 
            // strings value and continuing processing as normal.
            if (qryCmd.Contains(";"))
            {
                char[] delimitChar = { ';' };
                string[] splitQueries = qryCmd.Split(delimitChar);
                qryCmd = splitQueries[0];
                GetiSeriesData(qryCmd);
                qryCmd = splitQueries[1];
            }

            GetiSeriesData(qryCmd);

            // Display message if no records found.
            if (lvData.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found.");
            }
            lblRecCnt.Text = lvData.Items.Count.ToString();
            this.lvData.CheckBoxes = true;
        }
```

---

```
        public void GetiSeriesData(string query)
        {
            OdbcDataReader dr;
            try
            {
                //Set value of system based on table being looked at in ConnectionString
                string sysValue = "";
                if (query.Contains("lib1"))
                {
                    sysValue = "P";
                }
                if (query.Contains("lib2"))
                {
                    sysValue = "N";
                }

                MergeDocLibrary mdl = new MergeDocLibrary();
                dr = mdl.GetData(query);

                Int16 x = 0;
                string gndr = "";

                // Fill ListView Control lvData
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    lvData.Items.Add(dr["MEMNO"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["NAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR1"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ADDR2"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_CITY"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_STATE"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["OLD_ZIP"].ToString().Trim());

                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(sysValue.ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["LNAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    if (dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim() == "M")
                    {
                        gndr = "Mr.";
                    }
                    else // (dr["SEX"].ToString().Trim() == "F)
                    {
                        gndr = "Ms.";
                    }
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(gndr + dr["LNAME"].ToString().Trim());
                    lvData.Items[x].SubItems.Add(dr["CITY"].ToString().Trim() + ", " + dr["STATE"].ToString().Trim() + " " + dr["ZIP"].ToString().Trim());
                    x += 1;
                }

                mdl.closeConn();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

EDIT:

Solved it. `x` was getting reset to 0 on the second iteration, causing all of the SubItem data to be mismatched with it's Item, and nothing to be written to the fields. Made `x` a higher scope value and now everything processes just fine, all data present.

Comment: multi queries mean you may have different fields in the SELECT, you should take that into account. BTW, I would like to introduce the use of `OdbcDataReader.NextResult()` it allows you to loop through all the results in a semi-colon separated query (batch query). That way you can make a `do-while` loop while `NextResult()` returns true, in that while, you have another while loop while `Read()` returns true.

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for the heads up on the terminology specification. Any thoughts on my non-written data issue?

Comment: I'm not sure but as I said, you have multi-queries so you may have different fields in the SELECT for each query, if all the queries look the same like `SELECT A, B, C...` then I don't think there is any reason for the first query running OK (fills all `A,B,C`) while the second filling only 1 field (fills only `A`).

Comment: The queries were running perfectly, it was filling the ListView control that was bad. I figured out on the second iteration I was resetting `x = 0`, causing none of the subitem Data to get added. All good now, thanks.